# How to improve speed for query of large text in mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have the following schema for the database.

```
CREATE TABLE `std_reslt` (
       `student_id` int NOT NULL,
       `date` date NOT NULL,
       `info` LONGTEXT,
       `result ` LONGTEXT, 
       `result_ids` LONGTEXT,
       `sid` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY KEY(student_id)
PARTITIONS 50;
CREATE INDEX `student_date`
ON date_uri_pair (`student_id`, `date`);
CREATE INDEX `date_sid`
ON date_uri_pair (`date`, `sid`);
```

The info contains the serialized string value. The serialized data is the collection of a large number of JSON string. This is so huge that we need to divide the data into multiple rows for the same date. Now when we try to query the database using the below query it takes a long time to get the result especially when the range of dates is larger.

```
SELECT info, result_ids FROM std_reslt WHERE student_id =30 AND date >= '2019-05-01' and date<= ''2019-05-30'
```

I need to get the data, deserialize info which contains data as:

```
[{"john":35, "john":75, "Haris":30, "Haris":40 .....}]
```

The goal is to find the top N records by adding all the value of info such as:

```
[{"john":110, "Haris":70}]
```

Is there any other datatype other than the LongText because I think InnoDB uses a different approach for LongText data. If I try to deserialize the data and store each data in a separate column then the size will be very huge

Comment: "If I try to deserialize the data and store each data in a separate column then the size will be very huge" - Did you try, or calculate, or just guess? (Also, unrelated, but what are you using for JSON parsing where `{"john":35, "john":75}` is not useless?) However, +1 and <3 for putting the SQL schema in your question, I wish all SQL questions were like this.

Comment: Why are you storing `result_ids` in a single row? Why not use a one-to-many relation table?

Comment: Because of a large number of data for result_ids. For each student id and for each date there are around 5000 records. So for 300 students and for 30 days of data, there will be around 30*300*5000. Same goes for result and info column.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE INDEX `student_date`
ON date_uri_pair (`student_id`, `date`);
```

```
 WHERE student_id =30 AND date >= '2019-05-01' and date<= ''2019-05-30'
```

You have a series of conditions and you have multiple column index.
Try separating the indexes,   one for date,  and one for student.

Comment: This is bad advice. Only one index can be used per table; in OP's case, `student_date` covers both columns being queried, and is the optimal scenario (first find the student 30, then within that find the date range). In your case, the more discriminatory of your two indices would be selected, and the found results would need to be scanned row-by-row for the other column's criteria. That means, adopting your suggestion would reduce the disk space use (by reducing the index size), but increase the query processing time (contrary to OP's inquiry).

Comment: what if their programs decided to use date only?
It makes sense to create another index.   Creating another index doesnt hurt.  "using" too many indexes is the sketchy part.   If you cant understand my advice then there is something lacking on your experience.

Comment: OP is not here asking about another query. OP is asking about _this_ query. And _this_ query's optimal index is `(student_id, date)`. Separating `student_date` into `student` index and `date` index _increases query time_ for _this_ index. Also, if there was a query that needed `date` but not `student`, it would be covered by the other index, `date_sid` (but it is also irrelevant to the question being asked).

Comment: For now, I need to get the data by student id and date so I guess the optimal index is ```(student_id, date)```